# If every bounded sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence, then the inner product space is Hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, weak-convergence

We can prove that in Hilbert space, bounded space has a weakly convergent subsequence, as we can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396961/bounded-sequence-in-hilbert-space-contains-weak-convergent-subsequence) or  [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177782/every-bounded-sequence-has-a-weakly-convergent-subsequence-in-a-hilbert-space?rq=1). Does the converse hold?

That is, in an inner product space $H$, if every bounded sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence, is $H$ complete?

**My work:**

I thought it is a good start to look at a bounded sequence in an incomplete inner product space. As we see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39810/canonical-examples-of-inner-product-spaces-that-are-not-hilbert-spaces), the space of the sequence which has finitely non-zero element is incomplete. Then I tried to make a bounded (but not weakly convergent) sequence in this space, but I am failing to do so.

How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be the completion of $H$. Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $H$. Then $x_n$ tends to some element $y$ of $K$. Let $x_{n_k} \to x$ weakly in $H$. Let $F$ be a continuous linear functional on $K$. Then $\lim F(x_n)=F(y)$ . By weak convergence of the subsequence we must have $\lim F(x_n)=F(x)$ (since the restriction of $F$ to $H$ is a continuous linear functional on $H$).   Thus $F(y)=F(x)$  for al $F\in K^{*}$ which implies $y=x \in H$.